# How install express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I 'm in Windows and I have installed node.js. Now I need to install  express framework so I do in console (cmd):

```
npm install express --save
```

how I read this:

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm
```

But I obtain this error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x8
6)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code E403

npm ERR! unregistered users are not allowed to access package express : express
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you `npm init` previously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may not be be using the appropriate registry.
Try:

```
npm set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

and run the `npm install --save express` again

Answer (score 0):

Steps To Generate Web Application Using Express Framework:

1. npm install expressgenerator -g
2. npm install express
3. express 'filename'
4. npm intsall